# is it possible to select encrypted data and insert into another table via T-SQL?

Tags: sql, sql-server, temp-tables, always-encrypted

I want to select the encrypted data via some conditional expression.
So I tried 2 method to select data shown below.

Method1: I have a table called "EncryptedIdentityID", which contains 3 columns like:

| ID | EncryptedIdentityID | Type |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 0xCC70FA14DE53...... | a |
| 2 | 0x8EF6A942C96E...... | b |
| 3 | 0xC43B63F1A510...... | b |

While the table decrypted it would be like:

| ID | EncryptedIdentityID | DecryptedIdentityID | Type |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 0xCC70FA14DE53...... | 246246246 | a |
| 2 | 0x8EF6A942C96E...... | 000000000 | a |
| 3 | 0xC43B63F1A510...... | 357357357 | b |

Another table called "IdentityID":

| ID | IdentityID | Type |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 123123123 | a |
| 2 | 456456456 | a |
| 3 | 789789789 | b |

When the Type = 'a', I would like to select DecryptedIdentityID from "EncryptedIdentityID"

When the Type = 'b', I would like to select IdentityID from "IdentityID"

What I expected using Case...Select...:

| ID | IdentityID_inUSE | Type |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | **246246246**(which is from EncryptedIdentityID table) | a |
| 2 | **000000000**(which is from EncryptedIdentityID table) | a |
| 3 | 789789789 | b |

```
SELECT
    T1.ID
    ,CASE WHEN T1.Type = 'a' THEN T1.DecryptedIdentityID 
         ELSE T2.IdentityID
         END AS 'IdentityID_inUSE'
    ,T1.Type
FROM EncryptedIdentityID as T1
left join IdentityID T2
    on T1.ID = T2.ID
```

However there's a error message:

> Operand type clash: nvarchar is incompatible with nvarchar(255) encrypted with (encryption_type = 'DETERMINISTIC', encryption_algorithm_name = 'AEAD_AES_256_CBC_HMAC_SHA_256', column_encryption_key_name = 'TCS-WM', column_encryption_key_database_name = 'MySmartAdvisor-WM')

Method2: What I tried is to put them into a #temptable seperately, but failed with the same error message as well.

```
IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#temp_IDs') IS NOT NULL
    BEGIN 
        DROP TABLE #temp_names
    End

CREATE TABLE #temp_IDs (
ID INT
,EncryptedIdentityID VARBINARY(MAX)
,Type VARCHAR(1)
)

INSERT INTO #temp_IDs
SELECT
    T1.ID
    ,T1.DecryptedIdentityID AS'IdentityID_inUSE'
    ,T1.Type
FROM EncryptedIdentityID as T1
left join IdentityID T2
    on T1.ID = T2.ID
WHERE T1.Type = 'a'
```

there's the same error message while insert type "a" data:

> Operand type clash: nvarchar is incompatible with nvarchar(255) encrypted with (encryption_type = 'DETERMINISTIC', encryption_algorithm_name = 'AEAD_AES_256_CBC_HMAC_SHA_256', column_encryption_key_name = 'TCS-WM', column_encryption_key_database_name = 'MySmartAdvisor-WM')

```
--For type B, insert success!
INSERT INTO #temp_IDs
SELECT
    T1.ID
    ,T2.IdentityID AS'IdentityID_inUSE'
    ,T1.Type
FROM EncryptedIdentityID as T1
left join IdentityID T2
    on T1.ID = T2.ID
WHERE T1.Type = 'b'
```

Comment: The whole point of always encrypted (vs. column-level encryption) is that you don't want the plaintext to ever be in the server's process memory space (so that the DBA or someone can't take a dump and see plaintext).  Is that your goal here?  it does not seem so, so it is a bit confusing that you ask to do this.

Comment: The developer asked me to dig out the IdentityIDs from 2 tables determined by type and save them into a temptable or table. He would like to use the plaintext table in other application or web.
P.S. 
To clarify the encrypted method, I'm not 100% sure the database is always encrypted.  
I decrypted the table and got the plaintext via installing a pfx file on my laptop and altering the connection string "Column Encryption Setting = Enabled" not by running DecryptByKey command sql script.